# Why does this function that finds the min and max of an unordered list not work in certain scenarios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, comparison

This code is supposed to recursively find the min and max of an unordered list by breaking the list in half. Once in half it calls the function again on each half. There are two exceptions, if the list has only 1 item it just returns that item as both min and max. If the list has two items then it compares those two items directly and returns the appropriate min and max. Here is the code.

```
import random

unordered = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
#x = 0
#while x < 10:
#   unordered.append(random.randrange(0,100))
#   x += 1

print(unordered)

def minMax(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0], x[0]
    if len(x) == 2:
        if x[0] > x[1]:
            max_ = x[0]
            min_ = x[1]
        else:
            max_ = x[1]
            min_ = x[0]
        return max_, min_
    if len(x) > 2:
        global min_, max_, maxA, maxB, minA
        a = x[:len(x)//2]
        b = x[len(x)//2:]
        maxA, minA = minMax(a)
        maxB, minB = minMax(b)
        if maxA > maxB:
            max_ = maxA
        if maxB > maxA:
            max_ = maxB
        if minA < minB:
            min_ = minA
        if minB < minA:
            min_ = minB
        return max_, min_

print(minMax(unordered))
```

This returns (4, 1) for some reason.
When I set unordered = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] it thinks that 3 is the min but it correctly identifies 5 as the max.

Comment: What's with the `global min_, max_, maxA, maxB, minA`? Why are you using globals?

Comment: (Also you forgot `minB`.)

Comment: You're not dealing with the case where `maxA` and `maxB` are equal (same for the mins). Admittedly that can't be the problem with this list, but it will be in some cases.

Comment: @user2357112 yes that was a separate question I asked on Reddit, "Am I using global correctly". It was giving me errors and doing that somehow fixed it? I'm not very good at this

Comment: Global variables and recursion do not mix.

Comment: @user2357112 I just commented out that line of globals and it fixed it?? Now I am even more confused than I was before, what was global doing to screw it all up?

Comment: @JohnGordon Should I not bother trying to understand precisely how it cocked it up and just know not to do it again?

Comment: @Retsek: Your recursive calls were stomping all over each other's data because they were trying to share the same set of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

As `unordered` is a list. Why not use [Python's max function](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/max/), rather than write your own?

`>>> unordered = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]`

`>>> max(unordered)`

`5`

Otherwise why not something as simple as

`def min(list):
    min = none
    for x in list:
        if min == none:
            min = x
        elif x < min:
            min = x
    return min`

Comment: Yes sorry I should have made this clear. I am aware that Python has it's own max function but as a learning exercise I was attempting to make my own.